# How can I fix the Syntax Error in the subquery?

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

I am trying to find the Age based off date of birth. I keep getting a syntax error in the subquery.

I'm getting on error on the - CUST_DOB /365,0) As Age from customer; to use the correct syntax. Error Code 1064

```
SELECT  CUST_LNAME, CUST_FNAME, ROUND((NOW() – CUST_DOB)/365,0) AS AGE
FROM    CUSTOMER;
```

Comment: What is the error which you are getting?

Comment: @RahulTripathi I'm getting on error on the  - CUST_DOB /365,0) As Age from customer; to use the correct syntax.  Error Code 1064

Comment: Please check Arun's answer!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a problem with the minus (-) sign. please use it like

```
SELECT  CUST_LNAME, CUST_FNAME, ROUND((NOW() - CUST_DOB)/365,0) AS AGE
FROM    CUSTOMER;
```